# Как более компактно проверить что переменная существует и является непустым массивом?

Tags: php

Как можно сократить код и более расширенной сделать проверку массива?

```
// проверка на все не соответствующие значение, в том числе и на отсутствие самой переменной
$result = null;
$result = 1;
$result = [];
$result = 'строка';
$result = false;
$result = ['data'];
$result = [null];

$result['data']['list'] = [1, 2]; // это должен быть единственный корректный вариант

if (isset($result['data']['list']) and is_array($result['data']['list']) and !empty($result['data']['list']) {
  // ........ если все нормально, то работаем с массивом
}
```

Comment: одновременно писать isset и !empty - бессмыслица

Comment: почему среди некорректных нет $result['data']['list'] = [] и $result['data']['list'] = 'строка'?

Comment: Сейчас не ясно ничего. Что должно быть на выходе и почему. И на что в целом что проверяется (должно проверяться)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да вроде понятно же из кода, $result['data']['list'] должен существовать, и быть не пустым массивом. Хотя лично по мне, пустой массив вполне имеет право на существование

Comment: Хотя про "более расширенную проверку" непонятно, да. Что требуется расширять, куда и зачем - это действительно, загадка. Может, надо не расширить, а углубить?

Comment: @Ипатьев без isset выдаст ошибку если переменной не существует, !empty массив не должен быть пустой. Вообщем хочу исключить всевозможные ошибки

Comment: `$result['data']['list'] = [] и $result['data']['list'] = 'строка'` это тоже некорректные

Comment: ДААААА? Вот прямо возьмет и выдаст? А если раз в жизни прочитать описание empty в документации?

Comment: а почему $result['data']['list'] = [] некорректный? Какую ошибку он вызовет?

Comment: И снова - что за такая "расширенная проверка массива"? Или это "хочу проверить но не знаю что"?

Comment: А что этот код должен делать, если проверка не прошла?

Comment: @Ипатьев это я там получаю по api и с помощью `json_decode($output, true);` перевожу в массив. Из этого нужно проверить массив на корректность и если в нем есть данные ключ с непустым внутри массивом то работаем с ним, В остальных случаях просто игнорируем

Comment: $result['data']['list'] = ['data', []]; корректный? А кто это должен знать?

Comment: @Ипатьев к стати вы правы, isset наверное можно не писать

Comment: $result['data']['list'] = ['data', []]; корректный

Comment: предлагаю в проверку добавить `&& count(...) == 2`

Comment: @ArchDemon не факт что там только два. Но если и использовать count, то тогда не добавить, а заменить empty на неё.

Comment: @Ипатьев, тогда нужно возвращать `isset`. По комментариям и вопросу я понял, что элементов должно быть строго 2, не важно каких.

Comment: @Ипатьев ну вот, смотрю, всё же, не понятно, что нужно)

Comment: А вопрос, на самом деле бредовый. По причине того, что не может от апи приходить ответ такой, чтобы было верно сразу  и `[1,2]` и `['test', 234]` и `['data', []]`. Ответ у апи строгого формата. Там чётко обозначено что приходит и, что-что, а, если в зависимости от погодных условий элементом будет число, а потом строка или вообще массив - бред .

Comment: попробуйте pipeline